# How to load bootstrap into plugin admin page on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I can't seem to get bootstrap to load in my plugin on admin pages, here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
function add_admin_page () {
    $settingsPage = add_options_page('Course Listing Page','Course Listings', 'manage_options', 'admin-course-listing', 'admin_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_admin_page');

    function loadBootstrap() {
        wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', plugins_url('', __FILE__) . '/js/bootstrap.js' );
        wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', plugins_url('', __FILE__) . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
    }

    function admin_page() {
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'loadBootstrap' );
    //other code relating to admin stuff

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML code? Are the lines to load the files there? Have you checked the debugger of your browser for loading errors? Is jQuery loaded (it is necessary for bootstrap and you neither load it nor do you have it as a dependency for bootstap.js).

Comment: It looks like bootstrap has been added but the css isn't displaying as bootstrap would.

Comment: Bootstrap is built as a standalone framework while WordPress provides basically the same for its admin area. It is quite possible that these two collide. Personally I wouldn't bother trying to make Bootstrap work in the WordPress admin area, I'd just use the same classes WordPress uses to make my own plugin pages fit in with the overall design and usage.

Comment: Fair point, I just wanted pretty tables setup for me.